# Global object database on Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm writing you because I would like to create a global object ( Database). I have my class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {}
```

In my first activity I use

```
DatabaseHelper db;
```

and I store data. but In my second activity I would like to delete information in db.

For that I have in my class

```
 public  boolean deleteTitle(String name)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
        return db.delete(DB_Table, ID + "=" + name,null)>0;
    }
```

But I don't know how to use this method on second activity for an object in the first activity.

Finally I can't find my file AndroidManifest.xml.

[Structure of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkoeB.png)

Comment: i think you can create one activity which can extend application and on its onCreate you can initialize your db and create a public function that will return you db object...you can access this through out your application

Comment: have you tried singleton pattern ?

Comment: Please add your additional code again as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

While not providing a solution to your problem (More information like your table structure would be needed), judging from your picture, your project is quiet small yet, so I would highly recommend you to switch to the Room framework for your database (SQLite wrapper).

Then you can bind your data to the view via a proper ViewModel which is common practice.

Here you can find a codelabs explaining you the procedure in detail.

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view#0